# Splitting arrays in unequal chunks using np.array_split: overcomplicating?

Tags: python, arrays, octal

I am trying to convert an octal number to decimal.

The inputs are a set of strings as numbers such as "23", or "23 24", or "23 24 25". My code works for inputs like this, but cannot handle say "23 240", or "23 240 1" I.e. when the inputs are of different lengths, the array splits them incorrectly.

I think I've overcomplicated it by using arrays. Is there a way to assess each input individually (i.e. "23" then "240" then "1"), and then put these back into the desired output "19 160 1"?

Code:

import numpy as np

def decode(code):

```
decimals = []
code = code.split()

for n in code:
    p = len(n)
    for digit in n:
        decimal = int(digit) * (8**(p - 1))
        decimals.append(decimal)
        p -= 1

split_input = np.array_split(decimals, len(code))

sum_decimals = []

for number in split_input:
    sum_decimal = sum(map(int, number))

    sum_decimals.append(str(sum_decimal))
separate_outputs = " ".join(sum_decimals)

return str(separate_outputs)
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more! what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Sorry. I want to take sets of numbers such as "34 35" "1 3 4 5". This would be "code". Convert this to a list, splitting the different parts, i.e. [34, 35]. Then use the equation detailed in the code to convert to decimal (i think my code does this okay). Then sum the parts (i.e. decimal for 3 + decimal for 4). Then return the decimal for each of the inputted numbers (i.e. for [34, 35] = "28 29" (exactly like this)).

Comment: Can you explain how [34, 35] = "28 29"

Comment: It's octal to decimal. So octal 34 is decimal 28. i.e. from base8 to base10.

Comment: I am just confirming, that you are entering a string of space-separated numbers which you want to split into lists and return as a decimal to octal converted as a string, right? And your input is coming from I/O like keyboard

Comment: Yep! Space separated outputs too.

Comment: My code essentially works. The issue is when you get the arrays towards the end, it splits them equally, but this falls down when your input is not of equal size (i.e. different digit lengths: 23 456 678. It can do 23 45 67 or 1 2 3 4 5 or 5678 6898 9695.

Comment: Please try the answer, and let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

*Does this work? Try running it in an instant interpreter such as [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)*

**CODE:**

```
import numpy as np

def decode(code):
  if isinstance(code, str):
    decimals = []
    code = code.split(' ')
    for n in code:
        p = len(n)
        for digit in n:
            decimal = int(digit) * (8**(p - 1))
            decimals.append(decimal)
            p -= 1

    split_input = np.array_split(decimals, len(code))
    sum_decimals = []

    for number in split_input:
        sum_decimal = sum(map(int, number))

        sum_decimals.append(str(sum_decimal))
    separate_outputs = " ".join(sum_decimals)

    return str(separate_outputs)
```

**INPUT:**

```
str1 = input('Enter octals:') #23 240 1
decode(str1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
19 160 1
```

**EXTRAS:**

1. If you copy code make sure to adjust tabs because that could lead to
   multiple errors.
2. Also, you could put an `else` statement to raise
   error if function does not receive a string array. OR, you could add
   multiple `if...else` statements to handle different data formats
   like: `str`, `int`, `list`, `tuple`, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much Shisui. It certainly now works with 23 240 1 giving 19 160 1. However, when I try a very long sequence such as: "2 3 5 7 13 15 21 23 27 35 37 45 51 53 57 65 73 75 103 107" it does not work. It gives "5 12 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 64 67 0 7"

Comment: @EdMasters if it helped, please mark it as ok, so that others can avail it as well